# How to install NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Rather than spend hours trying to figure out if the source that I googled will work right or not, can someone tell me how I install drivers for my GTX 780?

I tried following this one http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081649 after downloading the .run file from the NVIDIA website.

But I committed a newbie sin by typing something into the terminal blindly without verifying what it does exactly.

sudo service lightdm stop

Typing that made my screen go blank with no way of doing anything except a hard reset.

Any answers appreciated for this day 2 linux noob.

Answer (score 2):

First remove all NVIDIA software you have installed.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

Now install the NVIDIA drivers from the repositories.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Another GUI way is to open the system settings and select "Software and Updates". You'll find an "Additional Drivers" tab there. Selecting this tab displays you the available drivers for your system. It should also list the proprietary NVIDIA drivers.